# Cannot access jakarta.servlet.FilterChain

Tags: java, spring-boot, frontend, backend, angular-fullstack

I was writing an application in intellij idea using springboot.When I tried to run the program it showed cannot access jakarta.servlet.FilterChain
bad class file: /C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 11.0/lib/servlet-api.jar!/jakarta/servlet/FilterChain.class
class file has wrong version 65.0, should be 61.0
Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath. I have added jakarta.servlet dependency too.I tried adding the servlet jar file to the classpath still the issue hasn't been resolved.I also trie mvn clean,install(it didn't help)This is my classpath:C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 11.0\lib-servlet-api.jar.I have given the dependencies for your reference.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.10</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
        <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>23.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin.external.google</groupId>
        <artifactId>android-json</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.20131108.vaadin1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.9.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
        <version>9.0.78</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I have also enclosed the error for your reference.Let me know the solution at the earliest.Thanks in advance.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvzPE.png)

Answer (score 1):

You're running Tomcat 11, [which requires Java 21 / class version 65](https://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html), but you're running Java 17 (class version 61).

I'm not sure why you are running such a new version of Tomcat but such an old version of Spring boot, my I think you have some dependencies mixed up. I'd recommend removing Tomcat 11 for now since it's not officially released yet at this stage (it's 11.0.0-M10 at this time of writing)